# Date coming through as NULL when data type is set to "date" in csv/t

Tags: qgis, date, null

If I set the data type to `date(DD-MM-YYYY)` in the CSVt file the date comes through but as a String/text.  But I really need it to be date type.

My CSV field looks like this:

```
NAME,DATE,TIME,SPECIES
CAM6119,19/01/2022,10:51:02,Stoat
```

My CSVT file looks like this

```
"String","Date","Time","String"
```

This comes through with Date column all NULL

If I do CSVT like this:

```
"String","Date(DD-MM-YYYYY)","Time","String"
```

the date comes through but the data type is text/String.

Comment: Your format string has a hyphen, but the data has a slash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your date is not a date. It is a string representing a date. A [date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is in format `yyyy-MM-dd`. You can convert it to a date once you loaded your data as string, e.g. by adding a virtual field via field calculator with this expression:

```
to_date("DATE",'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

*It can come to confusion with date formats as many software products have built in handlers for different date representations. But QGIS uses the GDAL CSV driver, which only supports real dates, see https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html*